# Is there anyway for IE11 to support BigInt?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, outlook-addin

I tried to look for answers here in stackoverflow and in google for any way to support BigInt in IE 11. Has anyone been successful in adding support BigInt for IE (and old versions of Safari)? Currently I am working on an addin which uses BigInt. Running the outook-addin in IE throws a BigInt undefined error.

I am currently looking at these two :

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi

https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

Comment: No - BigInt isn't supported in IE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: I think there's no way to support `BigInt` in IE 11. I also tested the BigInteger.js and it can't make `BigInt` work in IE 11. JSBI seems also doesn't support IE 11. Transpiling `BigInt` is an extremely complicated process, which incurs hefty run-time performance penalty. It’s also impossible to directly polyfill `BigInt` because the proposal changes the behavior of several existing operators.

Comment: @YuZhou Thanks for your answers. As for JSBI, there might be a way to make it work for IE (https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/47) But i have yet to try it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you @ShreyasBhat. I have seen that reference too.

Comment: No worries. You can have a try and let us know your test result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much a dupe of this :
[Outlook/IE failing to run addins using BigInt data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63786622/outlook-ie-failing-to-run-addins-using-bigint-data-type/63825691#63825691)

Just in case :

Here is what I did to  make BigInt work for my Outlook-Addin in IE11 :

1. Installed/added the [JSBI Library](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi) into my project.
2. Added some dataview polyfills, from [JSBI-dataviews](https://gist.github.com/graup/815c9ac65c2bac8a56391f0ca23636fc). Please see my comments.
3. Also based some modifications on [elk-chat](https://github.com/elk-chat/elk_web/blob/master/packages/sdk/bigint-buffer.ts)

I hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. There were never plans for it to add Support for Internet Explorer and as Micrsoft drops support for IE soon, I don't think there will be coming anything for it. Take a look at the [MDN page for BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I saw the table of browser that support bigint and that IE is not supporting BigInt. However, if I were to use either BigInteger/JSBI libraries, and replace all my "BigInt" reference in my code, with the one for BigInteger or JSBI, do you think that will work? Thanks.

Comment: I really can't tell, I'd say just try it it and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you again for your thoughts. I have found a way to make BigInt work with IE somehow.

Comment: Nice! How did you do it? (Also it's always helpful to leave it for future users who may encounter the same issue)

Comment: the answer below is what I did. I am marking it as an accepted answer. Thank you again. I am a long time lurker here in stackoverflow, it feels good to contribute. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a try at this npm library. A calculator utility to perform arbitrary arithmetic computation, with the help of JSBI-based BigDecimal.

> npm install jsbi-calculator

It works in IE11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Jsbi-calculator Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbi-calculator/dist/jsbi-calculator-umd.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const expressionOne = "((10 * (24 / ((9 + 3) * (-2)))) + 17) + 5";
    const resultOne = JBC.calculator(expressionOne);
    console.log(resultOne);
    // -> '12'

    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    const isIE11 =
      userAgent.indexOf("Trident") > -1 && userAgent.indexOf("rv:11.0") > -1;
    let max;
    // MAX_SAFE_INTEGER not available in IE11
    max = isIE11 ? "9007199254740991" : String(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);

    console.log(max);
    // -> '9007199254740991'
    const expressionTwo = max + " + 2";
    const resultTwo = JBC.calculator(expressionTwo);
    console.log(resultTwo);
    // -> '9007199254740993'
  </script>
</html>
```