# Outlook/IE failing to run addins using BigInt data type

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, office-js

Outlook currently uses IE11 as its backend when executing Javascript. Since IE does not fully support ES6/ES2015, IE fails to execute code using "BigInt".

I know for a fact that Microsoft is planning to end support for IE next year. So the chances for IE to be updated to support ES6 is probably almost zero-percent.

In this light, I would like to ask advice on any of the following points :

1. Is there a way to force outlook to use microsoft Edge as its backend?
2. Is there a way to get IE to support BigInt (or ES6 fully for that matter)?
3. Is there any possibility at all that IE supports ES6 before its end of life?

Thank you very much.

Comment: 2, no, 3, not a chance, it's been left to rot for years now by microsoft - I am seriously surprised it's not end-of-life already (technically, I'd say IE died in about 2005, just that Microsoft didn't know it was dead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help and answers. Today, I was able to make BigInt work with IE11 and old versions of Safari.

Although, I have not tested the entire BigInt library with IE, I have tested my solution on how to make BigInt work on IE just enough for my needs. I will continue to test though. And if anybody reading this finds a better fix, i hope you can share too.

Here is what I did to make BigInt work for my Outlook-Addin in IE11 :

1. Installed/added the [JSBI Library](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi) into my project.
2. Added some dataview polyfills, from [JSBI-dataviews](https://gist.github.com/graup/815c9ac65c2bac8a56391f0ca23636fc). Please see my comments.
3. Also based some modifications on [elk-chat](https://github.com/elk-chat/elk_web/blob/master/packages/sdk/bigint-buffer.ts)

I hope this helps everyone.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Would be a no. From memory, Outlook uses it's own HTML renderer.
2. Probably, have you tried [bigint-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-polyfill)?
3. Only with a polyfill

Comment: Thank you. I will try this one and get back to you when i get this working. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to force outlook to use microsoft Edge as its backend?

The browser used by Outlook depends on your OS and Office 365 versions. You could refer to the table in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins). If you want to use Microsoft Edge browser in Outlook, I think you need to update your OS version or Office 365 version according to below:

[image]

For question 2, I think it's impossible and I gave my opinion in your question before.

> Is there any possibility at all that IE supports ES6 before its end of life?

No. From the [statement of Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support): *Security updates, compatibility fixes, and technical support continues for IE 11 on Windows 7, 8.1, and 10.* It means Microsoft has no plan to continue adding features to Internet Explorer 11. So IE 11 won't support ES6 in the future and we can only use polyfill or babel to transpile some ES6 code for IE 11.