# How do I use the BigInt library with HTA applications?

Tags: html, jscript, hta

This code throws an error that BigInt is unrecognized:

```
<html><head>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="HelloExample" 
   BORDER="bold" 
   BORDERSTYLE="complex"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Message Sender</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function Test()
{
  var x = BigInt(5);
  alert(x);
}
</script></head>
<body>
<center><h2>Message Sender</h2></center>
<input type='button' value='test' onclick='Test()' />
</body></html>
```

Is there a metatag or setting that allows me to use the native Javascript BigInt in a .HTA application?

Comment: You're probably out of luck because MSHTA is based on the IE9 engine and supports VBScript and JScript (ECMASCript v3) not modern JavaScript. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65751321/692942) may explain a bit more, it's in relation to Classic ASP but it's to do with VBScript and JScript so is relevant.

Comment: Also [What's the difference between JavaScript and JScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135203)

Comment: Maybe a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63772893/is-there-anyway-for-ie11-to-support-bigint

Comment: user692942 above is correct. I'm out of luck because MSHTA is based on the IE9 engine.